# loop not working properly, also needing data validation

Tags: c

This may be a simple answer. I have only been programming with C for a month.
I am creating a C-program that the user is presented with a menu 1-4.
Menu options 1-3 ask the user for an integer, when an integer is input, the program writes or "draws" that amount of "dots" or periods.
Each of the first options will do the same function, but a while loop, do-while loop, and a for loop respectively.
The only way to terminate program is to select 4 at the main menu.

My question is how to get my program to loop back and continue to work properly.
When i execute the program it works correctly the first time, but when the program loops back to the main menu. No further options work. IE: if i try the input an integer again for the "dot drawing" it doesnt work correctly.

I am also Having trouble validating input on either menu for letters or "non numbers", at the moment if you input a letter it breaks the program.

Im not sure what to do and where to go with this.
Im not needing the code re-written, perhaps just some ideas of where to take it. 
I'll accept any references or links provided.
a copy of my incomplete program is included below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{




system("cls");

int programRun=0;
int menuSelection=0;
int absmenuSelection=0;
int dotNumber=0;
int countNumber=0;
char enter;

while(programRun==0)
{
system("cls");
printf("\nplease make a number selection\n");
printf("Please select a choice:\n");
printf("[1] While loop...\n");
printf("[2] Do-While loop...\n");
printf("[3] For loop...\n");
printf("[4] Exit program...\n\n");

scanf("%d%c",&menuSelection,&enter);
    absmenuSelection= abs(menuSelection);


   if (absmenuSelection <1 || absmenuSelection>4)
    {
    }
    switch (absmenuSelection)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("\nPlease input a number for the amount of dots you wish to see...");
            scanf("%d", &dotNumber);
            if(dotNumber > 0)
            {
                while(countNumber<dotNumber)
                {
                countNumber++;
                printf(".");
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("\nsorry, that is an invalid response. Now you have to try again.\n");
                }
            printf("\n");

          system("pause");
          break;

        case 2:
              printf("\nPlease input a number for the amount of dots you wish to see...");
              scanf("%d", &dotNumber);
              if(dotNumber > 0)
              {
                do
                {
                countNumber++;
                printf(".",countNumber);
                }
                while( countNumber<dotNumber );
              }
              else
              {
                printf("\nsorry, that is an invalid response. Now you have to try again.\n");
              }
          printf("\n");
          system("pause");
          break;

        case 3:
              printf("\nPlease input a number for the amount of dots you wish to see...");
              scanf("%d", &dotNumber);
              if(dotNumber > 0)
              {
                  for(countNumber=0;countNumber<dotNumber;countNumber++)
                  {
                      printf(".",countNumber + 1);
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                printf("\nsorry, that is an invalid response. Now you have to try   again.\n");
              }

          printf("\n");
          system("pause");
          break;

        case 4:
            while(programRun>1)
            programRun=1;
            printf("\nOkay have a nice day");
            return 0;

        default:
               printf("\nsorry that is an invalid statement, try again\n\n");
               system("pause");
    }}

system ("pause") ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you have this ? --- `scanf("%d%c",&menuSelection,&enter);`... why not just `scanf("%d",&menuSelection);` ?

Comment: use fgets instead e.g. `char buffer[128]; fgets( buffer, 128, stdin ); menuSelection=atoi(buffer);`

Comment: @sukhvir That's a hack because `scanf()` wouldn't read the newline otherwise, and it would fail on the next iteration. But I must admit it's horrible. Use `fgets()` and `strtol()` instead.

Comment: @claptrap Much rather `menuSelection = strtol(buffer, NULL, 0);`. And check the return value and `errno()` to handle errors properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working well .....

Set after each `case:`  `countNumber=0;`

or try

```
if(dotNumber > 0)
            {
countNumber=0;
/*REST */
}
```

**otherwise   case 1:  case 2: will not work if i try 2 times after giving  dotNumber  a higher value at first and lower at last**

**EDIT:**
The C library function void isdigit(int c) checks if the passed character is a decimal digit character.

```
 if( isdigit(variableHere) )
   {
      //is a digit
   }
```

**Sample  o/p**

```
please make a number selection
Please select a choice:
[1] While loop...
[2] Do-While loop...
[3] For loop...
[4] Exit program...

1

Please input a number for the amount of dots you wish to see 4
....
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: "Set after each case: countNumber=0;" that answer solved my loops not working on multiple tries.
Now i just need to work on the number validation.

Comment: @LanceJensen  glad to help u , if this is an answer to ur Q dnt forgot to Aceept it ... :)

Comment: I still need to figure out how to get correct input validation.  IE: the program not to accept letters. (and know how to use said input validation)

Comment: inserted this:" if( isdigit(menuSelection) )
        {
            menuSelection=0;
        }"           right after my first scanf and in between absvalueSelection and it works for less than a second.  as far as i can think if the isdigit fails to return 1 it will convert menuSelection to zero and that should default the case and say try again.